# How to define global variables in flash cs5.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, flash-cs5, flash-cs5.5

I can't find if there is a way to define a variable which can be accessed from anywhere in the project in Actionscript 3.0 using Flash CS5.5.

I tried this:

```
_global.myScore = 0;
```

which i got from [adobe_website](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000052.html) but it didn't work.

Can anyone help or give any clue?

EDIT: I just tried the most easiest way and it looks like it's working but i'm not sure. I just created a new layer and i defined the variable in the first frame:

```
var myvar:int=0;
```

Is this way correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try static variable, declared in some class:

```
public static myScore:int = 0;
```

use:

```
SomeClass.myscore += 1;
```

but be careful not to use them too much or too often - in terms of optimization, they are not so good.

Static members are members of the class, not the instance, and you can't use them within regular function - the function has to be static too.

Comment: _Static members are members of the class, not the instance, and you can't use them within regular function - the function has to be static too._
That's not true, actually.